# I need help giving function to my edit button when clicked to edit the shopping list item, then saving changes

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom-events

after searching, I don't know where to start to give edit button functionality so the code that I did try, I've already deleted. My delete button is fully functional by the way. I thought an if else statement would work but I yielded no results.

```
// submit event
```

type here

```
//create form

const form = document["addItem"]
const div = document.querySelector('#todos')
const ul = document.querySelector('#list');

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
    // addItem event handler for submit event on submit
      const typedInput = document.getElementById("title").value
      console.log(typedInput) 
      const list = document.getElementById("list")
      document.addEventListener("click", addItem);
      
      
      // created elements and appended to list to display on the website
      const div = document.createElement("div")
      const ul = document.createElement("list");
      const li = document.createElement("li");
      div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(typedInput));
      ul.appendChild(li);
      li.appendChild(div);
      // added button to represent the edit button when clicked
      const button = document.createElement("button");
      button.name = "edit";
      li.appendChild(button).textContent = "edit"
      
// added newButton to store delete button, appended to the parentElement to remove the list item
//after submission
      const newButton = document.createElement("button");
      newButton.name = "removeItem";
      li.appendChild(newButton).textContent = "X"
      document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
      newButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
          this.parentNode.remove();
          
        
       
          
      })
     })
```

Comment: `const form = document["addItem"]` - Should this be as it is now, or should it be something like `const form = document.querySelector("#addItem")`? Or perhaps `const form = document.getElementById("addItem")`?

Comment: no, it works as is because it has id of name and that's how its extracted, using bracket notation. I'm sure it can be done as querySelector as well.

Comment: How are you attaching the `click` even listener to your `Edit` button? I can only see two attached click event listeners in your code (ignoring the submit one): one for the add button, and one for the remove / X button.